# How do I split a string by the first delimiter and ignore the rest?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying

```
df[['home', 'away']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
```

However I get this error.

```
    df[['home', 'away']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', expand=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3597, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_array(key, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3634, in _setitem_array
    check_key_length(self.columns, key, value)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexers.py", line 428, in check_key_length
    raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I want the column to be split by the first instance of delimited and ignore the rest.

How can I limit this?

Comment: pass `n=1` in `split()` method.......see the documentation of [`split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: like this: `df[['home', 'away']] = df['game'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)` ?

Comment: yes like that..